# fast url query with R

Tags: r, url, benchmarking

Hi have to query a website 10000 times I am looking for a real fast way to do it with R

as a template url:

```
url <- "http://mutationassessor.org/?cm=var&var=7,55178574,G,A"
```

my code is:

```
url  <- mydata$mutationassessorurl[1]
rawurl  <- readHTMLTable(url)
Mutator  <- data.frame(rawurl[[10]])

for(i in 2:27566) {
  url  <- mydata$mutationassessorurl[i]
  rawurl  <- readHTMLTable(url)
  Mutator  <- smartbind(Mutator, data.frame(rawurl[[10]]))  
  print(i)
}
```

using `microbenchmark` I have 680 milliseconds for query. I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it!

Thanks

Comment: If the website **server** is the bottleneck, then no. How fast can you go if you do nothing apart from get the web page and do no other processing on it?

Comment: If you're connecting to the same server, you can save quite a lot of time by keeping the http connection open. httr will do this by default for you, with RCurl, you'll need to manually manage a handle object.

Comment: Did you know that you can post multiple queries at one time (submitting the form on the front page) `library(RCurl); library(XML); readHTMLTable(postForm("http://mutationassessor.org/", vars=c("hg19,13,32912555,G,T\nhg18,7,55178574,G,A")))[10]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to speed up http connections is to leave the connection open
between requests. The following example shows the difference it makes
for httr. The first option is most similar to the default behaviour in
RCurl.

```
library(httr)
test_server <- "http://had.co.nz"

# Return times in ms for easier comparison
timed_GET <- function(...) {
  req <- GET(...)
  round(req$times * 1000)
}

# Create a new handle for every request - no connection sharing
rowMeans(replicate(20, 
  timed_GET(handle = handle(test_server), path = "index.html")
))

##      redirect    namelookup       connect   pretransfer starttransfer 
##          0.00         20.65         75.30         75.40        133.20 
##         total 
##        135.05

test_handle <- handle(test_server)
# Re use the same handle for multiple requests
rowMeans(replicate(20, 
  timed_GET(handle = test_handle, path = "index.html")
))

##      redirect    namelookup       connect   pretransfer starttransfer 
##          0.00          0.00          2.55          2.55         59.35 
##         total 
##         60.80

# With httr, handles are automatically pooled
rowMeans(replicate(20,
  timed_GET(test_server, path = "index.html")
))

##      redirect    namelookup       connect   pretransfer starttransfer 
##          0.00          0.00          2.55          2.55         57.75 
##         total 
##         59.40
```

Note the difference in the namelookup and connect - if you're sharing a
handle you need to do each of these operations only once, which saves
quite a bit of time.

There's quite a lot of intra-request variation - on average the last two
methods should be very similar.